# How to redirect users to their activities in retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I have a user-type which are users and supervisors .. on login I want users to go to use health data activity and supervisors to go the dashboard activity.

here is my code for login.

public void login user(String email, String password) {

```
    Call<ResponseBody> call = RetrofitClient
            .getInstance()
            .getApi().login(email, password);

    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Authenticating please wait...");
    progressDialog.show();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, UserHealthDataActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                loginRequest = new LoginRequest(email, password);
                String loginRequestJson = gson.toJson(loginRequest);
                PH.get().setObjectAsJsonString(getApplicationContext(), "LOGGED_IN_USER", loginRequestJson); //save the login details to shared preference
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            System.out.println("throwing ..." + t);
            loadingBar.dismiss();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: what is the issue that you're facing?

Comment: I want to redirect to the different activity

Comment: What's the json response of the url that you are hitting ? The json reponse must be having some values depending upon which you can redirect user to specific page.

Comment: @HectorStanley, what is the response of the login API?

Comment: it's throwing a null pointer exception when I added the code: if(users.getUserType().equals("user")

Comment: the issue has been resolved. thanks you